# run vba code to extract price from redfin

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to run VBA code from excel to navigate to redfin.com, search for an address, extract the home price from the html and write the price in cell 'A2'. Not sure if there is an easier way of doing this with python or some other way but I've been struggling to get this working for a while.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchRedfin()
    
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim searchUrl As String
    Dim searchAddress As String
    Dim priceStartIndex As Long
    Dim priceEndIndex As Long
    Dim price As String
    
    ' Address to search for
    searchAddress = "Address here"
    
    ' Create xmlhttp object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Construct the search URL
    searchUrl = "https://www.redfin.com/"
    
    ' Navigate to the search URL
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", searchUrl, False
    xmlhttp.send
    
    ' Wait for the response to finish
    Do While xmlhttp.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ' Check the status of the response
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        ' Search for the address
        xmlhttp.Open "GET", searchUrl & "stingray/do/address-autocomplete?location=" & Replace(searchAddress, " ", "+"), False
        xmlhttp.send
        
        ' Wait for the response to finish
        Do While xmlhttp.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        ' Check the status of the response
        If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
            ' Extract the price from the search results
            priceStartIndex = InStr(xmlhttp.responseText, "<div class=""info-block price"">")
            priceEndIndex = InStr(priceStartIndex, xmlhttp.responseText, "</div>")
            price = Mid(xmlhttp.responseText, priceStartIndex, priceEndIndex - priceStartIndex)
            price = Replace(price, "<div class=""info-block price"">", "")
            price = Replace(price, "$", "")
            
            ' Write the price to cell A3
            Range("A3").Value = price
        Else
            ' Handle error
            Debug.Print "Error: " & xmlhttp.Status & " - " & xmlhttp.statusText
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle error
        Debug.Print "Error: " & xmlhttp.Status & " - " & xmlhttp.statusText
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you are pretty far along with that code. What isn't working?

Comment: Your issue looks to be with the stingray URL you're building - it's not creating a valid URL so you get a 404 error.